# The response to the AWS AppSync query doesn't have any data. (Using Amplify in an Android app)

Tags: android, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-sdk-android

(I am a beginner) I am trying to do an AppSync query from my Android app with Amplify. I'm following the steps as in this page- https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/api#run-a-query  After executing the following code,

```
  public void query(){
        mAWSAppSyncClient.query(ListTodosQuery.builder().build())
                .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK)
                .enqueue(todosCallback);
    }
```

The GraphQL Callback response is supposed to be like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listTodos": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id" : ...
        }]}}}
```

But I keep receiving the response as:

```
com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response@df0e853
```

It doesn't have any other data. Why is this so? Why is the response in this format?

(I tried running the listTodos query in the AppSync console and I get the right response there, with data and all the items in the DynamoDB)

Answer (score 2):

`com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response@df0e853` is the instance of the response object. You should be able to access `response.data()`:

````
    private GraphQLCall.Callback<ListTodosQuery.Data> todosCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<ListTodosQuery.Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<ListTodosQuery.Data> response) {
            Log.i("Results", response.data().listTodos().items().toString());
            // do something with response.data() here
        }
        // ...
    };
    ```
````

Comment: response.data() is always null. (the same query when run in the console gives the right data)

Comment: Maybe there's something in response.errors() that would help you debug this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the response.hasErrors() is true. I have posted this issue in detail here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/1269  Even though I get the reponse.errors() message, I am not able to figure out where I'm going wrong.